# Google Apps Script that "does nothing" in a custom function if condition is not met in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I am trying to create a custom function in Google Sheets using Google Apps Script, but when the condition is false, instead of leave the cell alone, it deletes what is there and leaves it blank, when I need it to simply "not do anything" (leave the last value). The script I have is:

```
function score(a,b) {
 var today = new Date();
 var deadline = new Date(a);
 if (today <= deadline && b != 0){
     return b;
  }
}
```

The idea here is that, every day the function presents a cell value ("b") that also changes its contents every day up until a certain day which is set in another cell ("a"), then leaves the last value that was put there. The problem here is that, the day after, instead of leaving the last value, it leaves the cell empty.

The custom function ends up being `=SCORE(F10,B10)` (F10 is the deadline date, and B10 has the value that changes every day. The custom function is in H1.)

I have tried putting an "else" condition but that did not work either (like else {return;} or else {return false;} ), but nothing has worked. How can I make it so it puts the last value there. Is there a way to save the last value somewhere and then put it there if there is no way to put a if... else "do nothing"?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest looking at your whole logic again. I'll just write you a sample script:

```
function mainFunction(){
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
   var myRange = sheet.getRange(1, 1);
   doNothing(myRange.getValue());
}

function doNothing(a){

  if(a <= 100){
    Logger.log("less than or equal to 100");
  }else{

  }
}
```

When the value is 100, it fulfills the condition:

```
[18-01-21 ] less than or equal to 100
```

When the value is greater than 100, it does exactly nothing, nothing is printed on the logs.

Answer (score 0):

In contrary as occurs with onEdit triggers, Custom functions are not able to get the value before starting the recalculation.

To validate this I made the following custom function

```
/**
 *
 * @param {number} newValue
 * @customfunction
 */
function test(newValue) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var cell = ss.getActiveCell();
  var oldValue = cell.getValue();
  return [[newValue,oldValue]];
}
```

Values and formulas

```
  |    A    |      B        |      C      |
--+---------|---------------|-------------|
 1|        1|=test(A1)      |             |
```

Result

```
  |    A    |      B        |      C      |
--+---------|---------------|-------------|
 1|        1|              1|#ERROR!      |
```

One alternative is to use the Properties Service to store the old values

Example

The following function is an improvement of the above example, just to show the use of the Properties Service.

```
/**
 *
 * @param {number} newValue
 * @customfunction
 */
function test2(newValue) {
  var DocumentProperties = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
  var key = 'test2:' + 
     SpreadsheetApp
       .getActiveSpreadsheet()
       .getActiveCell()
       .getA1Notation();
  var oldValue = DocumentProperties.getProperty(key);
  DocumentProperties.setProperty(key, newValue);
  return [[newValue, parseInt(oldValue,10)]];
}
```

Notes:

- If the argument value is a reference to a blank cell or a string the value second value will be #NUM!
- It's assumed that the function will be used on a single sheet by spreadsheet. If you plan to use your function on several sheets, add the sheet name to the key or another way to prevent overwriting the same key from different sheets.
- It's used 'test2:' as a key prefix. You could use something more appropriate for the purpose of your script.
- The calls to the Properties Service are slow so it could be unsuitable for uses cases where the custom function will be applied to tens or hundreds of cells because the 30 seconds execution time limit for custom functions.

One way to apply the above to the function on the question is the following:

```
function score(a,b) {
  var DocumentProperties = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
  var key = 'score:' + SpreadsheetApp
    .getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getActiveCell()
    .getA1Notation();
  var oldValueString = DocumentProperties.getProperty(key);
  var today = new Date();
  var deadline = new Date(a);
  if (today <= deadline && b != 0){
    DocumentProperties.setProperty(key, b);
    return b;
  } else {
    return parseInt(oldValueString,10);
  }
}
```

Related

- [Conditional formatting for "Loading..." cells](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41815241/1595451)